# How to take 10 000 samples out of a dataset in r?

Tags: r, sample, boot

I want to take a sample of 400 out of a data frame with 2000 rows, the way to do that is simply

```
s1 <- sample_n(t, 400)
```

Now I want to do that 10000 times. I guess boot() is the function to use here to avoid an overload but I don't know what I need to write as the function part to get what I want

```
boot(t, ?, 10000)
```

Can anyone more experienced with r help me out here?

Comment: What about `lapply(1:10000, function(x) sample_n(t, 400))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also `replicate` the random sample using `sample_n` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(replicate(10, df %>% sample_n(400), simplify = F))
```

Please note: change the 10 to 10000 for 10000 times.

#### Random data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = runif(2000, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! It takes a bit to load but it works and I can calculate with the results without problems